# How do I set specific <li> in navbar to the right side?

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar

I'm trying to set specifc links in my navbar to the right side once a user is loged in. I've tried using pull-right and float-right and neither of them worked. Does anyone now why? Here is my code:

```
  <header style="background-color:black">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-toggleable-sm border-bottom box-shadow mb-4">
        <div class="container">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")" class="navbar-brand">
                
            </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent"
                    aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse d-sm-inline-flex flex-sm-row-reverse">
                <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1 ml-auto">

                    @if (user.isAuthenticated)
                    {
                       
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light">Hello user!</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link text-light" asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="UserIdentity">Logout</a>
                        </li>
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
```

I wanted the li tags "Hello user!" and "LogOut" to appear on the right side of the navbar. I've seen a couple of examples but most of the times the nav bar class is configured differently than mine. I'm new to bootstrap so I'm not sure how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use bootstrap flex display class to shift the nav to right: this is the class you can use along with all the existing classes

```
d-flex justify-content-end
```

Comment: That was it, I deleted the ml-auto part. The final result was <ul class="navbar-nav flex-grow-1 d-flex justify-content-end"> and the links are now on the right side of the navbar. Thank you!